# Do I have to use Views to use all the behaviors of OpenLayers maps module?

Tags: javascript

I just started using the http://drupal.org/project/openlayers module. There are plenty of tutorials to learn about it, but all of them make use of **views** to show the maps.

I need to show a simple map to show a single the location. I need this map to show a marker and a tooltip with some information (address, phone,...)

I tried showing a map in a node by adding the **geofield field** to a content type and then setting the **OpenLayers Map Widget** in manage display.

The map is shown up fine but as far as I see there no way to add a **popup** to the map.

Then my question is: Do I need to show the maps through a view to get all the **behaviors** provided by the module?

Comment: IMHO, using openlayers to show a single map, with a single location is unbelievable overkill. Just embed a google map. It will show a single map with a signle location and tooltip popup.

Comment: maybe you are right but I've been using gmap for a while and now I'd like to move to openlayers. I'm learning about OL and this shouldn't be so difficult to accomplish. If I need to use view I'll go that way, but I'd like to have some advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The learning curve is a little steep when first working with openlayers if you really want to use it you can create your map and add a geoJSON layer to it and just write the geoJSON code in the textarea provided to create the point and popup info. Checkout openlayers plus module for more behavior options.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, 
you have to create a **Views** for that (using a Nid argument to show only the specific node location point) and show that map as block after/before node content. 
I had the same problem last week and this is the most easy way to get a map with popups.

Answer (score 0):

you have create a view for that content type to create an open layer overlay & then you can easily enable that layer in behaviour section you just need to enable your created openlayer overley layer pop up layer .